# Disable delete items in a site from central admin

Tags: 2010, permissions, central-administration, site

From memory I know it is possible to restrict the options in a site from central admin. I want to remove the rights to delete items. How can I do this from central admin to stop site collection admins being able to assign the delete permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only control it at the WebApplication level:

Application Management | Manage Web Applications | Select WebApp | User Permissions (Ribbon button)

Comment: If you remove the delete item permission can site collection admins still delete?